# Java config.properties file in Git

Tags: java, eclipse, git, bitbucket, egit

I have a Java Project which includes a config.properties file, in which this config.properties file has property values of paths to some executable files.

I've configured a Git Repository (using EGit eclipse) tool, but the application is simply not working due to the fact that the config.properties file is not included in the Git Repository (in gitignore) since all users who will push/pull to Git will have a different config.properties file.  How shall I solve this problem?  Is there a way to map the config file without including it to the repository.

Any help is highly appreciated, and I'm quite sure theres a solutions to this problem. 'Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you expect users to get this properties file if not from git?

Answer (score 2):

A way could be to gitignore config.properties, and add a config.properties-template with all parameters and comments explaining how to fill them if needed.

Comment: Solved.  What I did was to include a piece of code whick will create a config.properties file with default values if none are found.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. What I did was to include a piece of code whick will create a config.properties file with default values if none are found. –